# Adding UINavigationController with back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add a navigationcontroller to my iOS app.  I need all of the views except the "home" screen to have a back button but I'm not sure how to add it.

Here is a link to my project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv0y3oh1aftxl95/KFBNewsroom%204.zip

Comment: please don't post you code here and expect use to solve it. Do some research, tell use what you have tried and where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the navigation bars from all of your NIBs and use a navigation controller (such as in the app delegate like NeverBe outlined), and then transition to the child controllers via a `pushViewController` rather than `presentViewController` as you're currently doing, and you should get your "back" button automatically. You'll also want to remove any references to `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, if you have any, as your back button will now do `popViewControllerAnimated` for you. If you need to programmatically pop anywhere, though, you can just used `popViewControllerAnimated`.

In your NIBs, you might also want to tweak the simulated metrics so you can design your NIBs with the navigation bar graphically represented, e.g.:

[image: simulated metrics for nav bar]

See the navigation controller section of the [View Controller Catalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1) and refer to the [`UINavigationController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I got the root view looking right with the navigationcontroller.  I'm still having problems with getting the nav bar with a back button to appear on other views.  For instance, in ListViewController which is a table view.  Also, when I change [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:NO completion:nil]; to [[self navigationController]pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];, it won't let me select a row in ListViewController to go to the webview.

Comment: Can you maybe show me an example of what you changed?  When I change [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:NO completion:nil]; to [[self navigationController]pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19103/discussion-between-rob-and-raginggoat)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[KFBViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBViewController" bundle:nil]];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Call new view controller

```
KFBYouTubeView *youtubeView = [[KFBYouTubeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBYouTubeView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:youtubeView animated:YES];
```

**Update:**

Method for add custom nav bar buttons

```
- (void)customizeNavigationButtonWithType:(NavigationBarButtonType)type
                          normalImageName:(NSString *)normalImageName
                        selectedImageName:(NSString *)selectedImageName
                                 selector:(SEL)selector {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:normalImageName];
    UIImage *imgPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedImageName];
    UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [customButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customButton setImage:imgPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [customButton addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
    switch (type) {
        case NavigationBarButtonTypeLeft:
            [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:btn animated:YES];
            break;
        case NavigationBarButtonTypeRight:
            [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btn animated:YES];
            break;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[self customizeNavigationButtonWithType:NavigationBarButtonTypeRight
                        normalImageName:@"create.png"
                      selectedImageName:@"create_highlight.png"
                               selector:@selector(pressButton:)];
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a back button in the interface builder in a nib file?  When I add that code, it messes up my button layout.

Comment: @RagingGoat You really want to use the navigation controller and remove all of your nav bars that you've added manually. Use the simulated metrics like I outline in my answer if you want the Interface Builder representation of your views to look right.